# For any probability density function f, does it always exists another probability g such that f = g∗g? (* means convolution)

Tags: probability, convolution, density-function

I just learned the theory of convolution between functions, for a probability density function, is there always existing another function g such that f = g * g (convolve with itself?)

Comment: What did you try? Two-element sets?

Comment: You are probably talking about probability density on $\mathbb{R}$. Have you learned about characteristic functions associated to a probability density function?   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58525/when-can-a-random-variable-be-written-as-a-sum-of-two-iid-random-variables

Comment: (In particular, the link given there, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_distribution, answers you question in the negative)